# Implementing "Try again" button functionality shown on the "No internet connection" activity

Tags: android

In my app when the "Add to Cart", "Pay Now" etc buttons are clicked I check for internet connection first and then proceed with the subsequent logic and when there is no internet connectivity available then I take the user to the `NoInternetActivity` where I show the "Try again" button.
When the "Try again" button is clicked and if the internet gets available this time around, then the same logic should get executed which was supposed to get executed when the "Add to Cart" or "Pay Now" buttons were meant to execute.
How do I make this work?

Comment: Dont make the internet check before making the call. make the API call and handle the failure case. In the failure case you can replace your fragment with another fragment which has try now button. When user clicks on the try now button, replace this fragment with the fragment which makes starts the api call and have the whole process repeat.

Comment: @Ezio: But how can I track which action should get retriggered when the "Try again" button is called because the same `NoInternetFragment` will be shown for the failure case of both the "Add to cart" and "Pay now" buttons. I cannot hardcode the trigger on the "Try again" button.

Comment: They are both failing for the same reason, which is no internet, why do you want to have different behaviours.

Comment: What I meant was, the scene is, `HomeFragment` -> `NoInternetFragment` AND `CartFragment` -> `NoInternetFragment`. If I click on the "Try again" button present in the `NoInternetFragment` then I should be taken to the previous fragment(Home or Cart). My question was how to track the previous fragment in `NoInternetFragment`. I ended up passing the fragment tag as argument to `NoInternetFragment` and matched it to the actual fragment and load it.